# Netbeans adding many jars in directory tree but not in same directory

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, netbeans-8.1

I'm trying to use [3D Utilities](http://isda.ncsa.illinois.edu/drupal/software/3D%20Utilities) in a model viewer that I'm writing.  I am having problems importing all of the jar files as the tree that is provided.  Is there a way in Netbeans to add a whole folder structure to the Library?  I've tried the `Add JAR/Folder`.  It shows the jars but I am unable to use them when making import statements.

I would rather not have to add each individual jar file by hand as there are many jars and they are already organized fairly well.

Any help would be great.

I am unable to convert my project over to maven due to networking issues on my side.